# Does this expression diverge or converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have the following expression:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n^2} \ {\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sqrt{n^2 - i^2}}} \ $$

I am not quite sure whether it will converge or diverge. Can somebody tell me how to figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

hint: $S_n = \dfrac{2}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}$

Comment: Hint didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting $$\frac2{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{n^2-i^2}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n2\sqrt{1-(i/n)^2}, $$
we recognize a Riemann sum for $$\int_0^12\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Is there any other way. Without using Riemann sum?

Comment: @Anonymous: what is the reason for avoiding it?

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{n^2-i^2} < \sqrt{n^2} $ so $( \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^2-i^2} ) < ( \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \sqrt{n^2} ) = \frac{2}{n^2} n \times n = 2  $  use comparison test.
So $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^2-i^2} < 2 $ so limit must be finite.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: As far as I can see you only proved the sequence is bounded. That is far from being enough to conclude its limit exists...

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann sum is the most rapid tool for obtain the convergence and the closed form. But if you want another way we can consider the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) and get $$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{2}-k^{2}}=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor t}{\sqrt{n^{2}-t^{2}}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function. Now, since $t-1\leq\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we have $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{t^{2}}{\sqrt{n^{2}-t^{2}}}dt-\sqrt{n^{2}-1}\leq S_{n}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\frac{t^{2}}{\sqrt{n^{2}-t^{2}}}dt
 $$ and the integral is not difficult to evaluate $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{t^{2}}{\sqrt{n^{2}-t^{2}}}dt\overset{t=n\sin\left(u\right)}{=}n^{2}\int_{\arcsin\left(1/n\right)}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)du
 $$ $$=\frac{n^{2}}{2}\left(\int_{\arcsin\left(1/n\right)}^{\pi/2}1du-\int_{\arcsin\left(1/n\right)}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(2u\right)du\right)
 $$ $$=\frac{n^{2}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\arcsin\left(1/n\right)\right)\right)
 $$ so, by squeeze theorem, we have

> $$\frac{2S_{n}}{n^{2}}\rightarrow \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is a concave function on $[0,1]$, the sequence given by

$$ S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$$
that is trivially bounded, is also an increasing sequence by the [Hermite-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) inequality or by [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality). Increasing and bounded implies convergent, hence
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} S_n = \sup_{n} S_n = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
since the integral is just the area of a quarter circle.